# usage of break statement in js

Tags: javascript, break

I've rarely used 'break statement'.

And I used it almost for the first time to pass Free Code Camp test.

I passed it but then I realized I don't know how exactly my code works.

below is my code.

```
function dropElements(arr, func) {

  var copy = arr.slice();

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(!func(arr[i])){
      copy.shift();
    }
  }

  return copy;
}
```

And what I found strange was that I passed 4 out of 6 of below list without 'break'.

But number 5 & 6, I couldn't pass them without break.

1. `dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4], function(n) {return n >= 3;});`
2. `dropElements([1, 2, 3], function(n) {return n > 0;});`
3. `dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4], function(n) {return n > 5;});`
4. `dropElements([1, 2, 3, 7, 4], function(n) {return n > 3;});`
5. `dropElements([0, 1, 0, 1], function(n) {return n === 1;});`

   - what I expected: `[1, 0, 1]` but got `[0, 1]` without break.
6. `dropElements([1, 2, 3, 9, 2], function(n) {return n > 2;})`

   - what I expected: `[3, 9, 2]` but got `[9, 2]` without break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 5 and 6, the condition is correct but when you call shift, the first item in the array is still being removed.

For example in 5,

[0, 1, 0, 1] -> arr[i] = 0, func(arr[i]) is false, copy = ([1, 0, 1])

[1, 0, 1] -> arr[i] = 1, func(arr[i]) is true, copy = ([1, 0, 1])

[1, 0, 1] -> arr[i] = 0, func(arr[i]) is false, copy = ([0, 1])

In the last iteration, even though 0 is passed, 1 is still being shifted that's why you get [0, 1].

Comment: thank you Mark. I should think deeper before writing code!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on chrome console and it is working. Maybe you should ask the freecodecamp directly about this problem.

Anyway, the break will always break you go out of the loop.

Comment: sorry, I uploaded "well working code" and I edited it into "no-break" version.